# How to access prop in console.log that we send through <a> tag when we click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, console.log

My code is like this:

```
<a eventkey={0} onClick={ (event) => console.log(event.target)} href="#">
    {i}
</a>
```

In `console.log` I want to see the `eventkey` value like 0.
But I'm getting the whole tag.

How should I get only the `eventkey` value?

Comment: Needs more quotation marks.

Comment: @Nikhil Patil, just sent you an answer. Let me know if that's helpful to you :)

Comment: How about storing the eventkey as a variable before adding it as a prop and then logging that variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need this to access your custom props.

```
event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("eventkey").value
```

Comment: Wow, that is a really **verbose** version of `getAttribute('eventkey')`.

Answer (score 1):

It's widely considered bad practice to make use of inline event listeners (`onClick`), which is why I rewrote your code to make use of `adddEventListener`. Please also note that `eventkey` is an illegal attribute name on `a` tags. Use `data-eventkey` instead, which allows you to read it using `element.dataset.eventkey`:

```js
const eventkeyLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-eventkey]'));

eventkeyLinks.forEach((link) => 
  link.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
    console.log(link.dataset.eventkey);
  })
);
```

```html
<a data-eventkey="{0}" href="#"> {i} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{1}" href="#"> {j} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{2}" href="#"> {k} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{3}" href="#"> {l} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{4}" href="#"> {m} </a>
```

You could also use a delegate listener which would work for dynamically added elements as well:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
  if (event.target.matches('[data-eventkey]')) {
    console.log(event.target.dataset.eventkey);
  }
})
```

```html
<a data-eventkey="{0}" href="#"> {i} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{1}" href="#"> {j} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{2}" href="#"> {k} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{3}" href="#"> {l} </a>
<a data-eventkey="{4}" href="#"> {m} </a>
<a href="#"> no eventkey here </a>
```

Comment: what if we have list of such <a>

Comment: Respect sir! Never seen this before How to be great Front End Dev like you ?

Comment: Keep learning and working on frontend, you'll get there eventually :D

Comment: This question is about `React`, where it's [perfectly acceptable](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to use the `onClick` listener.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<a eventkey={0} onClick={ (event) => console.log(event.target.value)} href="#"> {i} </a>
```

Comment: No sir It return tag